# Formatting the SSD with one partition or two?

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd

I am preparing to format all my drives and install the Windows 8.1 now that I purchased the 850 Pro 256GB.

What I'm trying to ask is:

Is it better to create a partition only for Windows (around 60GB) and install all the programs in the other Partiton (178GB)?

Is leaving unallocated space for over-provisioning in W8.1 required or leaving free space will do just fine?

Thank you.

Comment: Depends if you think you're likely going to need to reformat the Windows partition in future and keep your data on the other. Personally I like the Ian of two separate partitions. You can configure partitions during the Windows install process. Set a size for Windows and leave the rest "unallocated" until Windows has successfully installed. Then format the "data" partition afterwards...

Comment: Be careful, however, UNDERprovisioning the partition size for Windows can cause big headaches if you fill the 60GB. Extending the partition whilst you have data on the other can be almost impossible...

Comment: Once you create a partition of a certain size that's all you get. You can grow and shrink partitions but they come at a price if the right-adjacent partition has data on it that needs shifting to the right to grow the left-hand partition.

Comment: Think about it like extending your house when the house next door is already there. You have to move that house first (and possibly cause it lots of damage in the move) before you can extend your house.

Comment: I understand. What about having one SSD partition for everything (Windows and Programs). Will this slow down the SSD after some time when a good percentage of space is filled up? Do you recommend leaving some unallocated space (I think 24GB might be fine)

Comment: Personally I would use the entire disk for everything (or add an additional HDD for my data), install Windows and my programs and make sure I have a regular backup of my precious data/files.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/808833/disadvantages-of-partitioning-an-ssd/808978#808978