# WIll partitioning an SSD make it slower?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, performance

Having read a number of SSD reviews, in particular, of those made by Crucial (a.k.a Micron), I've come to the conclusion that partitioning an SSD is going to make it slower. Here is the logic:

Those reviews explained that (at least the Crucial SSD's based on Marvel controllers) are essentially a RAID array of memory chips soldered to the board, invisible to the end-user as separate entities. I recall one or more of the reviews explicitly stated that the smaller capacity drive sequential access speeds were lacking because it had only half the number of chips of the larger drive. The slowdown was almost linear according to their testing. Thus, I conclude that when I partition such a drive, only a part of the chips are going to be in the partition, thus I'm going to suffer from the said linear slowdown.

Is the above true for Marvell based Crucials? For other drives such as Samsung-controller based, Sandforce-based, others? I'm particularly interested in the Crucial drives, them being the best bang for the buck right now. I'd be happy to also RAID a couple of those on an X79, but totally unsure about partitioning that either. However, that would be a separate question, and not a part of this one, so I'd like to first firgure out partitioning a single SSD drive.

Comment: Considering the drives already use whatever cells they desire for whatever address and there is no 1:1 mapping, the partitions can reside anywhere in the chips.

Comment: I don't think partitioning make any difference to speed in an SSD drive, as @SamiKuhmonen mentioned, there is no 1:1 mapping like in a spinning drive (normally), the drive will utilize the cells where if it wishes... How you partition it is not relevant. I have several SSD drives, benchmarking is pretty consistent whether it is one large volume or multiple smaller volumes.

Comment: Since IDE, we should not even be concerned with internal strategies.  The only issue with partitioning to affect performance in any way is alignment of the boundaries to geometry favored by the manufacturer. (Cylinder preferably, even though this is abstracted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense/logic.

> Those reviews explained that (at least the Crucial SSD's based on Marvel controllers) are essentially a RAID array

So it's a bad idea to partition RAID array too? That's new to me.

> I recall one or more of the reviews explicitly stated that the smaller
>   capacity drive sequential access speeds were lacking because it had
>   only half the number of chips of the larger drive.

But partitioning doesn't make your drive smaller. It's just a big drive, or big RAID in your word, "shared" by multiple partitions.

> Thus, I conclude that when I partition such a drive, only a part of the chips are going to be in the partition

A partitioned RAID-0 doesn't make it a JBOD.

Comment: I had absolutely no idea about the effect of partitioning a RAID before asking, thats' why I asked the question in the first place. As well as I had no idea on how the data gets distributed on the RAID.

Comment: Right partitioning is simply ranges of LBA's accessible as one drive, seperate from others.  If partitioning was a performance drag UEFI & recoverying partitions would NOT be accepted as part of a default install, nor would Linux installs happily seperate swap & user data from the main OS.    On an SSD, the LBAs are mapped in tables by the drive controller, as some point out the data might be striped on bit planes in a RAID configuration, so why on earth do people think partitioning implies some physical limited region of a disk, which simply doesn't use physical addresses to position data.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an useful answer here:
[Disadvantages of partitioning an SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/808833/disadvantages-of-partitioning-an-ssd)

According to @RobinHood answer, there are small differences regarding the SSD being Ram based or Nad-flash based devices. You'll only have a minor speed disadvantage (outlined below) in the case of Nand-flash based SSDs:

> Ram Based S.S.D.s:
>
> There is absolutely no disadvantage because they are random access!
>
> Nand-flash Based S.S.D.s:
>
> The only disadvantages that come to my mind would be:
>
> 1. Wear leveling won't have as much free space to play with, because
>      write operations will be spread across a smaller space , so you
>      "could", but not necessarily will wear out that part of the drive
>      faster than you would if the whole drive was a single partition
>      unless you will be performing equivalent wear on the additional
>      partitions (eg: a dual boot).
> 2. Like hard drives nand-flash S.S.D's are sequential access so any
>      data you write/read from the additional partitions will be farther
>      away than it "might" have been if it were written in a single
>      partition, because people usually leave free space in their
>      partitions. This will **increase access times for the data that is
>      stored on the additional partitions.**
> 3. Less total space increases the likely hood of writing fragmented
>      files, and while the performance impact is small keep in mind that
>      it's generally considered a bad idea to defragement a nand-flash
>      S.S.D. because it will wear down the drive. Of course depending on
>      what filesystem you are using some result in extremely low amounts
>      of fragmentation , because they are designed to write files as a
>      whole whenever possible rather than dump it all over the place to
>      create faster write speeds.

Comment: Copying someone else's SU answer to use as your own (even if you give credit) and adding no new insight seems like a form of plagiarism.  Downvoted.   You only deserve credit for finding a duplicate question that has an answer.

Comment: Sorry @sawdust, I'm new here. What should I have done then? Don't answer? Anyway I have to disagree with you. Searching for answers is also what science does, review articles seek to synthesize and summarize the work of a particular sub-field, rather than report on new results. And that also contributes to spread knowledge and authors are also given credit for their research. As in this case, extracting from a broader answer (disadvantages of partitioning a SSD) the exact contribution for this specific question (speed disadvantages) is not a contribution itself that helps with this issue?

Comment: I also thought this was not about credit, but about spreading good knowledge. This is an extract from the help section in this site:

"When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from another site or in an answer on Super User) make sure you do all of the following:

Provide a link to the original page or answer
Quote only the relevant portion
Provide the name of the original author"

I think I've done all the above mentioned... so your comment and downvote, IMHO are much out of place. [Help page - How to reference material](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Giving credit and spreading good knowledge is indeed laudable, however you are spreading misinformation.