# How low is "low free disk space" to trigger Windows 10 Storage Sense?

Tags: windows, windows-10

The default setting for Windows's Storage Sense system is to run "During low free disk space".

But how much does it consider "low"? I imagine this might be a fixed amount of space, or might be a percentage of the drive.

Answer (score -3):

Found some blog mentioning 200MB / 80MB / 50MB / 0MB as different levels to trigger different warnings, but this is older Windows 7 related:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/faq-low-disk-space-notification-or-warning-in-windows-7-how-to-disable-etc

It runs check every 10 minutes so if you are getting quickly low it may be too late.

I was not able to find official documentation so it may be subject to change or more dynamic in later Windows versions (even Windows updates in same version) if it is not documented anywhere. I heard some years ago (could already be or may be changed) that it used to be when lower than 10*√(disk in MB), which would be these:
64GB : 2.5GB, 250GB : 5GB, 500GB : 7GB, 1TB : 10GB

Personally I find it slower when getting to 10% left so I try to keep myself with at least 10% free. Some suggest leaving even more space for effective SSD trim operations, so perhaps 20-25% is more optimal:
[Does low disk space affect SSD performance?](https://superuser.com/questions/162155/does-low-disk-space-affect-ssd-performance)

Comment: Can you back this up with sources?